# Error referencing a matrix in a function to compute the in-degree of a node in an adjacency matrix

Tags: c, nodes, adjacency-matrix

```
int nodeInDegree(int *g, int node){
    int i;
    int count=0;

    for(i=0; i<COLUMNS; i++){
            if (g[node][i] == 1){
                    ++count;
            }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The above code keeps giving me an error for g[node][i] saying that the "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector"

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. `int *g` is equivalent to `int g[]`, so it's a 1D array, yet you're trying to access it like a 2D array.

Comment: Show the declaration for what is passed as parameter `g` from the caller. In fact, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an array as an argument (g), you need to send a 2d array or matrix, to do that change the argument from int *g to int **g

Edit:
I believe that what you need is something of this line

```
#include <stdio.h>
int nodeInDegree(int *g)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (g[i] == 1) ++count;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int mat[5][5] = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
    printf("%d\n", nodeInDegree(&mat[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my professor wrote up a template and that's how they wrote it so i haven't questioned it this entire time. i just tested it out though and i'm getting a seg fault. in main, they initialized a matrix with g_test[5][5] and referenced it by saying nodeInDegree(&g_test, i)

Comment: your matrix is initiated in the stack, so passing the entire matrix to the function won't work, you sould pass only one array of the matrix on the function call, instead of passing the node as an argument, try changing the function so that it receives only the array that corresponds to that node.
something like
`nodeInDegree( &g[node] )`

Comment: is g_test declared as a global variable or inside main?